# ggplot line graph with different line styles and markers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a line graph in ggplot2 that combines different line styles for some variable and different markers for other variables.

Example 1 graphs each variable with a different line style, Example 2 graphs each with a different marker, and Example 3 graphs each with different lines AND markers.

I'm trying to graph X2 and X3 with different line styles (solid, dashed) and then X4 and X5 as solid lines with different markers (circles, square, whatever).

Is there any way to do this??

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed <- 1
df <- data.frame(cbind(seq(1,10,1),matrix(rnorm(100,1,20), 10, 4)))
d <- melt(df, id="X1")

# Example 1: different line styles
ggplot(d, aes(x=X1, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable), size=1)

# Example 2: different markers for each line
ggplot(d, aes(x=X1, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point(aes(shape=variable, size=4))

# Example 3: differnt line styles & different markers (You see this graph below)
ggplot(d, aes(x=X1, y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=variable), size=1) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=variable, size=4))
```

[image]

Comment: As a first question, this is well written with a reproducible sample. Nice work!:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is one approach. You can use two more functions to control shape and line type. `scale_linetype_manual` allows you to manually assign line types. Likewise, `scale_shape_manual` allows you to manually assigns whichever shape you want.

```
# Example 3: differnt line styles & different markers
ggplot(d, aes(x=X1, y=value, color=variable)) + 
geom_line(aes(linetype=variable), size=1) +
geom_point(aes(shape=variable, size=4)) +
scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2,1,1)) +
scale_shape_manual(values=c(0,1,2,3))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks so much for your help. I'm obviously still learning all the features of ggplot2.

Comment: @learnmorer Pleasure. :) I am still learning ggplot2 everyday!

Comment: I think there is an error in the geom_point line. Size should be outside the brackets: `geom_point(aes(shape=variable), size=4)`

Comment: The correction provided by @luchonacho also removes the black dot '4' in the legend.